# How to display categories in a dropdown menu by retrieving the options from database in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want to display categories as options in drop-down menu by fetching the text from the database. When i call the object from views.py file in templates, categories are not displayed in drop-down.But on python shell the list of categories from database are displayed.

I have tried generic views as well but my problem is still there. I have also searched for my answer on stackoverflow but most of them in this regard are unanswered or if answered didn't resolve my issue.

**template.html**

```
 <select class="dropdown-menu" name="dropdown">
          {% for category in categorys %}
               <option value="{{ category.category }}">{{ category.category}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
 </select>
```

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
category = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

**views.py**

```
def CategoryView(request):
categorys = Category.objects.all()
context = {'categorys': categorys}
template = 'search_form.html'
return render(request, template, context)
```

Please if anyone could help?

Comment: `categorys` not `category_list`.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman i have modified that still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

adding dropdown-menu class to select seems to be creating problem. Remove the class and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much @JenishShrestha Sir. But my problem is still there. Please suggest any other way